# Разделить большой файл xml

Tags: php, laravel

Задача заключается в выборе файла на компьютере, его развибке и сохранении. Проект работает на фреймворке Laravel 5.8. Написал такой код

```
        $data = new \SimpleXMLElement($request->file('feed'), null, true);

    $json = json_encode($data);
    $data = json_decode($json);

    $strings = count($data->offer); //Общее количество строк
    $countString = 20000; // Количество записываемых в файл строк (для примера, их будет 20 000)
    $countFiles = intval($strings / $countString); // Целочисленное значение количества получаемых файлов
    $ostatok = $strings % $countString; // дробное число строк, оставшееся от деления

    $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Ads/>");

    //Создаем файл
    for($key = 0; $key < $countFiles; $key++) {
        // Записываем в него данные
        for ($i = 0; $i < $countString; $i++) {
            $item = $data->offer[$i];
            $offer = $xml->addChild('offer');
            $offer->addChild('type', $item->type);
        }
        //Сохраняем на диск
        $dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0');
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        $dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());

        $dom->save('files/feed'.$key.'.xml');
    }
```

Результатом исполнения сего шедевра стало получение двух файлов. В первом было записано 20.000 строк, во втором было записано два раза по 20.000 строк.

Вопрос такой - после записи 20.000 строк в первый файл нужно из массива $data их удалить, а оставшиеся записать во второй файл и сохранить. Как это сделать?

Спасибо.

Comment: Ну к laravel в оэтом фрагменте отношения нет вообще. Но я бы из `$data->offer` создал бы коллекцию (`collect()`), затем разбил бы коллекцию на `$countFiles` фрагментов (метод `chunk()` у коллекции) и уже обычным двухуровневым циклом обошел бы эти фрагменты коллекции

Comment: для "больших" файлов в целом то DOM из XML заружать чревато, а уж кодировать и декодировать в json для преобразования в массив, тоже не лучшая затея.

Comment: У  меня есть скрипт загрузки в бд, на локальном сервере 35.000 строк заливает за 7 сек. Но вот на реальном хостинге затык, не хватает памяти. я нашел программу под винду, которая делит большие xml файлы, разделил по 20.000 записей и залил в БД. Отсюда и родилась идея разделения файла на части. К тому же неизвестно, какого размера файлы придется в дальнейшем заливать